# Python failing to read lines properly

Tags: python, macos

I'm supposed to open a file, read it line per line and display the lines out.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import os
import re

in_path = "../vas_output/Glyph/20140623-FLYOUT_mins_cleaned.csv"
out_path = "../vas_gender/Glyph/"

csv_read_line = open(in_path, "rb").read().split("\n")
line_number = 0
for line in csv_read_line:
    line_number+=1
    print str(line_number) + line
```

Here's the contents of the input file:

```
12345^67890^abcedefg 
random^test^subject
this^sucks^crap
```

And here's the result:

`this^sucks^crapjectfg`

Some weird combo of all three. In addition to this, the result of `line_number` is missing. Printing out the result of `len(csv_read_line)` outputs 1, for some reason, no matter how many is in the input file. Changing the split type from `\n` to `^` gives the expected output, though, so I'm assuming the problem is probably with the input file.

I'm using a Mac, and did both the python code and the input file (on Sublime Text) on the Mac itself.

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: It works fine for me. I have a few style changes i'd make, but the actual code works fine. Are you sure you're only getting that as the output?

Comment: Perhaps the input file is using a different line terminator than the OS?  I could see this happening if you are on Windows and the input file uses CR as the line terminator (which is admittedly unusual).

Comment: @will, yes, I'm sure. It's driving me up the wall. I can change the contents of the input file, and it'll still give me only the last row, along with bits of previous rows if it's short. Of note is that the `line_number` does not appear.

Comment: @zack_falcon Try opening the data file in a hex editor to see what line terminator sequence it uses.  You are splitting on `"\n"` but it might be using something else.

Comment: if you iterate over the file object itself, without using read or split what happens?

Comment: @cdhowie, I'm using sublime, and regex find says it's `"\n"`.

Comment: Try using pythons [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)  functions and see if that fixes that.

Comment: I can get this output (on OSX) if the file uses CR for end-of-line, but works fine if LF or CRLF is used.  In both cases, the line numbers appear (which maybe you left out of your example).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be splitting on `"\n"` which isn't necessary, and could be incorrect depending on the line terminators used in the input file.  Python includes functionality to iterate over the lines of a file one at a time.  The advantages are that it will worry about processing line terminators in a portable way, as well as not requiring the entire file to be held in memory at once.

Further, note that you are opening the file in binary mode (the `b` character in your mode string) when you actually intend to read the file as text.  This can cause problems similar to the one you are experiencing.

Also, you do not close the file when you are done with it.  In this case that isn't a problem, but you should get in the habit of using `with` blocks when possible to make sure the file gets closed at the earliest possible time.

Try this:

```
with open(in_path, "r") as f:
    line_number = 0
    for line in f:
        line_number += 1
        print str(line_number) + line.rstrip('\r\n')
```

Comment: this will give different output, it will add a space between each line

Comment: The "b" modifier in open(...) only changes the way Winodws opens files -- in Linux it is exactly the same, but Windows does a distinction when reading text or binary files. I do agree, however, he should be using `for line in fd:`

Comment: @bconstanzo Nevertheless, one should use the correct mode in case the program is later run on a Windows machine.  Running on a Unixy system is not an excuse to be lazy and write unportable code.

Comment: @cdhowie indeed! I didn't mean to be lazy, I just thought it was worth noting that this is mainly a "Window-y" thing. I just don't think that the mode is affecting his program behaviour since he's running on Mac (thus, Unixy behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

So your example just works for me.

But then, i just copied your text into a text editor on linux, and did it that way, so any carriage returns will have been wiped out.

Try this code though:

```
import os

in_path = "input.txt"

with open(in_path, "rb") as inputFile:
  for lineNumber, line in enumerate(inputFile):

    print lineNumber, line.strip()
```

It's a little cleaner, and the `for line in file` style deals with line breaks for you in a system independent way - Python's [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) has universal newline support.

Answer (score -1):

I'd try the following Pythonic code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

in_path = "../vas_output/Glyph/20140623-FLYOUT_mins_cleaned.csv"
out_path = "../vas_gender/Glyph/"

with open(in_path, 'rb') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        print(str(i) + line)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several improvements that can be made here to make it more idiomatic python.

```
import csv

in_path = "../vas_output/Glyph/20140623-FLYOUT_mins_cleaned.csv"
out_path = "../vas_gender/Glyph/"

#Lets open the file and make sure that it closes when we unindent
with open(in_path,"rb") as input_file:

    #Create a csv reader object that will parse the input for us
    reader = csv.reader(input_file,delimiter="^")

    #Enumerate over the rows (these will be lists of strings) and keep track of
    #of the line number using python's built in enumerate function
    for line_num, row in enumerate(reader):
        #You can process whatever you would like here.  But for now we will just
        #print out what you were originally printing
        print str(line_num) + "^".join(row)
```

Comment: Why do you split the file on `^` characters, and then rejoin it on them?

Comment: I only split on them to show that it's possible to parse them using pythons csv module.  Then I joined on them to replicate what his original code did.  Really I just wanted to show that the lines could easily be split and parsed.  I figured that may be the intention based on his usage of "csv" in the origin post.